# Codable Failure Response Handler

Tags: swift, ios

Suppose You have two kind of response like one for success and one for failure

Success response model will looks like

```
struct UserLogin: Codable {
    let status: Bool?
    let accessToken: String?
    let data: [UserLoginData]?
   ....
}
```

Failure Model will looks like

```
struct FailedResponse: Codable {
    let status: Bool?
    let error: ErrorResponse?

}
```

How I handle this two responses

```
struct FailableResponse <T:Codable,E:Codable> : Codable {

    var success:T?
    var failure:E?

    public init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {

        let singleValue = try decoder.singleValueContainer()

        success = try singleValue.decode(T.self)
        failure = try singleValue.decode(E.self)

    }
}
```

And How I use `FailableResponse`

```
  APIClient.login(userName: self.loginViewModel.userName, password: self.loginViewModel.password) { (response:FailableResponse<UserLogin,FailedResponse>? , error) in

   }


// METHOD OF API CLIENT 
// API CALLING 
static func login<T:Codable>(userName:String,password:String,completion:@escaping completionResponse<T>) {
        self.performRequest(request: APIRouterUserModule.login(email: userName, password: password)) {(model) in

            self.handleResponseCallCompletion(result: model, completion: completion)
        }
  }
 // Parsing 
 private static func handleResponseCallCompletion<T:Codable>(result:Result<Any>,completion:@escaping completionResponse<T>) {
        let object = CodableHelper<T>().decode(json: result)
        completion(object.object,object.error)
    }
```

I think It can be more better

Any suggestion Please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches

1. For the sake of completeness, I’ll describe the typical, simple solution:

   ```
   struct UserLoginResponse: Codable {
       let status: Bool
       let error: ErrorResponse?
       let accessToken: String?
       let data: [UserLoginData]?
   }
   ```

   The `status` is not optional (because it’s presumably there regardless). But you can just decode this `struct`:

   ```
   do {
       let responseObject = try decoder.decode(UserLoginResponse.self, from: data)
       switch responseObject.status {
       case true:
           guard let accessToken = responseObject.accessToken, let userLoginData = responseObject.data else {
               throw ParsingError.requiredFieldMissing
           }

           // use accessToken and userLoginData here

       case false:
           guard let errorObject = responseObject.error else {
               throw ParsingError.requiredFieldMissing
           }

           // use errorObject here
       }
   } catch {
       print(error)
   }
   ```
2. If you really want to do this generic, wrapper approach, I’d suggest a slight refinement. Notably, the code in your question returns an object for which both the success and error objects are optionals. (There seem like there are a lot of `?` thrown in there quite liberally, whereas most API dictate “if success, *x* and *y* will be present, if failure, *z* will be present”.)

   I’d suggest, instead, a pattern that captures the fact that the response will be either success (when `status` is `True`) or failure (when `status` is `False`), and rather than returning both success and failure objects as optionals, use the `Result<Success, Failure>` enumeration with associated values, which is included in Swift 5. Or, if you’re using an earlier version of Swift, you can define it yourself:

   ```
   enum Result<Success, Failure> {
       case success(Success)
       case failure(Failure)
   }
   ```

   Then, the API response wrapper can have a non-optional `result` property of type `Result<T, E>`, where:

   - If `status` is `True`, parse the success object as a non-optional associated value which is the `Success` type;
   - If `status` is `False`, parse the error object as a non-optional associated value which is the `Failure` type;

   Thus:

   ```
   struct ApiResponse<T: Codable, E: Codable>: Codable {
       let status: Bool
       var result: Result<T, E>
       var error: E?

       enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case status, error
       }

       init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
           let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
           status = try values.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .status)
           if status {
               let singleValue = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
               result = try .success(singleValue.decode(T.self))
           } else {
               let parsedError = try .failure(values.decode(E.self, forKey: .error))
               error = parsedError
               result = .failure(parsedError)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you can do:

   ```
   do {
       let responseObject = try decoder.decode(ApiResponse<UserLoginResponse, ErrorResponse>.self, from: data)
       switch responseObject.result {
       case .success(let object):
           print(object.accessToken, object.data)

       case .failure(let error):
           print(error)
       }
   } catch {
       print(error)
   }
   ```

   This would seem to better capture the true nature of the response, that it’s either successful (and you get the non-optional success object) or it’s a failure (and you get the non-optional `ErrorResponse` object).

   By the way, I’d suggest that in this scenario, that `UserLoginResponse` be updated to reflect which fields are truly optional and which aren’t. For example, if you know that if `status` is `True`, that both `accessToken` and `data` will be present, then I’d make those non-optional properties:

   ```
   struct UserLoginResponse: Codable {
       let accessToken: String
       let data: [UserLoginData]
   }
   ```

Comment: No one does it better than you :)  , Thank for great explanation;